# Kotlin File Rename

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I am trying to run a simple operation of renaming a file, however it fails with 'false' result assigned to 'rename'.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

...

```
var dir=getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
var sourcefile=File(dir,"currentname.csv");
var destfile= File(dir,"newname.csv");
var rename=sourcefile.renameTo(destfile);
```

I am unsure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Do you have write storage permission ?

Comment: Just to make sure, before renaming just check if the file exists using `sourcefile.exists()`

Comment: As suggested above, depending on Android version, you are running on, you should check for the permission on runtime

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getExtenalFilesDir` with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`

```
var dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
```